# photoshop CS5 ver. 12.0.4 does not update to CR 8.2

Tags: lightroom, raw, adobe-camera-raw

How can I update my PS5 to camera raw 8.2. I run Lightroom 5 and when ever I want to edit a canon 550d CR2 file I get the warning that I need cr8.2! I downloaded the plug-in installed it "Successfully" but when I open PS it still runs on 6.4??
What do I do wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to update computer software and is not specific to photography.

Answer (score 2):

CR 8.2 is for Photoshop CC, and will not be usable by CS5 or CS6.

[Compatibility chart](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html)